# Youtube Api search returns unexpected results

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

With this request, I get many results and only the first one is the one I want (it has the search term in the video title):

```
Request: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={your_key}&channelId=UCsKrylY2g4-XOkVAQWkpv0g&part=snippet&q=yamatai
```

Result: https://pastebin.com/HR12bt61

But strangely enough, if I add the order param, then I only get one result:

```
Request: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={your_key}&channelId=UCsKrylY2g4-XOkVAQWkpv0g&part=snippet&q=yamatai&order=date
```

Result: https://pastebin.com/2eYbXXSE

How can this be explained?
Also, note that in both cases, totalResults=23 in both result sets. However, in the second case, requesting a second page leads to an empty set.
I also discovered that order=relevance (which is the default for order) returns all the results from the first set.

Answer (score 0):

Search is very weird in the Youtube api if memory serves it only searches in title.  Where the other ones are comming from i cant tel you the second one i think its a bug or just really weird

[Testing Link](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&channelId=UCsKrylY2g4-XOkVAQWkpv0g&maxResults=25&order=date&q=yamatai&_h=3&)

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCsKrylY2g4-XOkVAQWkpv0g&maxResults=25&order=date&q=yamatai&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"g7k5f8kvn67Bsl8L-Bum53neIr4/l7VBYhzL4sHmVrkUKgQ9UAR-Lgk\"",
 "regionCode": "DK",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 23,
  "resultsPerPage": 25
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"g7k5f8kvn67Bsl8L-Bum53neIr4/dB7MPu9wutwBJcpbzgegjKHDyko\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "3L_lIjAUnjg"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-10-03T21:26:28.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCsKrylY2g4-XOkVAQWkpv0g",
    "title": "Board Game 101 (EP85) Yamatai - Règles et Critique",
    "description": "Ce jeu est une gracieuseté d'Univers Ludo.*** Boutique en ligne: https://www.universludo.ca Page Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/universludo 0:36 - Intro 2:12 - Règlements 18:22 -...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3L_lIjAUnjg/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3L_lIjAUnjg/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3L_lIjAUnjg/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Professeur Board Game",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

It says `"totalResults": 23,` yet only returns one row.  I would post it as a bug on the issue tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%2B)

Comment: Yes, sounds like a bug to me too... The issue tracker link: is it hacked or what? I see only spam there...

Comment: Nope its Youtube API they hardly ever look at it but i will ping someone.

Comment: @DaImTo Did you ever get a follow up on this? Currently dealing with the same issue. Except in my case I get `totalResults: 1` and empty items list.

Comment: I have never heard back.    I have been trying for five years to get a contact on that team no luck so far